# How do I read an UTF 8 encoded text file into a text field?

Tags: utf-8, livecode

How do I read an UTF-8 encoded text file into a text field?

Comment: http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4067/l/20441-unicode  Step 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Unicode in LiveCode you need to be aware that LiveCode always works with UTF-16 encoded text (format depends on the processor your code is running on: big or little-endian). So to read in a UTF-8 encoded text file and display it you need to first convert the data to UTF-16.

When reading the file in you need to make sure that LiveCode doesn't automatically convert the line endings for you. The simplest way to do that is to use the `put` command with the `URL` keyword and a `binfile:` prefixed filename. Assuming the path to your file is in the variable theFilename this would read in the file contents while maintaining the integrity of the data:

```
put URL ("binfile:" & theFilename) into theText
```

Now that you have the data (still encoded as utf-8) in a variable you need to convert to UTF-16 using `uniencode`.

```
put uniencode(theText, "utf8") into theText
```

Now the text is now encoded as UTF-16 and you can display it in a field.

```
set the unicodeText of field "SomeField" to theText
```

Comment: Thank you, Trevor for the concise explanation. I used a test button "Load" with your code

Comment: `on mouseUp`
   `answer file "A text file"`
   `if it <> "" then`
      `put it into theFileName`
      `put URL ("binfile:" & theFilename) into theText`
      `put uniencode(theText, "utf8") into theText`
      `set the unicodeText of field "SomeField" to theText`
   `else`
      `--no file was selected, or cancel was pressed`
      `beep`
   `end if`
`end mouseUp`

Comment: http://lessons.runrev.com/spaces/lessons/buckets/809/lessons/12304-How-do-I-use-Unicode-in-Rev-

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the following in the dictionary:

useUniCode (property)
uniEnCode (function)
UniDeCode (function)

And in fact, any entry that has "uni" in its name.

Craig Newman

Comment: Yes, thank you, Craig. I now see that the uniEncode function in the dictionary has a user contributed comment which answers the question as well.

`put url ("binfile:/path/to/file/myUniText.ut8") into tRawTxt`
`set the unicodeText of fld "display" to uniEncode(tRawTxt,"UTF8")`

Comment: see also http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/6930-how-do-i-use-utf-8-text-with-fields